# How to escape commas in FileAppend in AutoHotkey?

Tags: autohotkey

I want to write the string "Hello,World" to a file and the following code does not work.

```
var1 = Hello
var2 = World
FileAppend, %var1% . "," . %var2%, C:\test.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a backtick to escape special characters like the comma delimiter.

**This writes "Hello,World" to `c:\test.txt`**

```
var1 = Hello
var2 = World
FileAppend %var1%`,%var2%, C:\test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Some options:

```
FileAppend, % var1 "," var2 , test.txt
```

or:

```
FileAppend, % var1 . "," . var2 , test.txt
```